# Saleor-Storefront does not show up on localhost:3000. Looks like storefront port is not bound to port 3000

Tags: saleor

In MacOS, I am unable to access saleor storefront on localhost:3000. I do not see any errors when after following the installation steps but the storefront container is NOT binding to port 3000.
These are my current checked out branches for saleor-platform:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApDA4.png)

This is how the container setup looks like. Please note that the saleor-platform-storefront-1 does not have the port bound to 3000:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxTX8.png)

This is how the docker-compose.yml file looks like in saleor-platform folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXMbT.png)

This is how the console output looks like after successful compilation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YeVs.png)

Now if I update the docker-compose.yml file with the following, the URL localhost:3000 is accessible but errors out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12U6s.png)

I get the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYzuR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Change docker-compose.yml file.

```
  storefront:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-storefront
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    #network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0
    #env_file: common.env
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).